# How can my JavaScript-function access the Web Property ID from the Google Analytics module?

Tags: 8, javascript, google-analytics

I use the [GoogleAnalytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module in most of my projects and have often the same issue:

Due to my countries policy requirements, every user has to be able to deactivate google-analytics [cookies](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-opt-out). To do so I need a little JavaScript to disable the cookie wich contains the UA/property ID, which is provided by the module.

Normaly such configs are set in the `drupal-settings-json` at the end of the page but there is no property-id in sight.

```
<script type="application/json" data-drupal-selector="drupal-settings-json">{"path":{"baseUrl":"\/","scriptPath":null,"pathPrefix":"","current....
```

is there any way for my JS-function to access this infirmation, or do I need to write an extra function to read the property ID and parse it to the drupal-settings-json somehow?

Comment: Have a look for the GA script in the page source - does it use a JS variable to pass the ID to the web service, or is it already in a string? If the former, you can use the same var in your JS code; if the latter you'll need to write a bit of PHP code like you thought

Comment: the module writes the code directly in the head without passing the variable.  but I hope there is still a way without writing custom functions. it seems to be a popular usecase (at least every german drupal website using analytics) and a standardized solution seems legit.

Comment: There isn't a way to do it with writing code. That could be the module developer adding a new feature, of course, but the functionality doesn't exist, so _someone_ needs to code it

Comment: I gues I know who needs to be this _someone_. tillthen, waiting for further comments / ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular Google Analytics module (google_analytics) relies on generating inline JavaScript snippets for initializing tracking, which can make altering its behaviour difficult - likely requiring patching the module.

[Googalytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/ga) is [a more flexible alternative for Google Analytics in Drupal 8](https://medium.com/myplanet-musings/a-different-approach-to-google-analytics-for-drupal-8-d9c3de218edf)

- `drupalSettings` is used to pass data to the front end.  This removes the use of inline JS, also making  the module compitible with [Content Security Policy](https://www.drupal.org/project/csp).
  The data structure isn't intended to be modified on the front-end by JS, but hopefully the improved control possible in the back-end makes it unnecessary.
- There's an open issue (with a patch currently needing feedback) for [integrating  with the EU Cookie Compliance module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ga/issues/3011324).  If this matches your use case you may not need to write any custom code, otherwise it may provide a template for how to override the module's JS library for your needs.